# How to copy files to a shared drive using batch or vbscript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, control-m

I have an existing vbscript which copy files to a shared location to a remote server, copying of files only permitted if executed by a logged in user having access to the drive. We would like to automate this via control-m but we need to implement either sftp or via vbscript to remove the manual execution of the script via user which has access to the location. Is their a way to do it via script which authenticates this process within a script without storing the password and do file transfer ?

Comment: Not understanding what you want to do it that way. `CONTROL-M` has SFTP functionality.

Comment: Edit your question and add the vbs code

Answer (score 0):

**Control-M for AFT is an excellent choice.**

For the transfer of files through FTP, FTPS or SFTP services I recommend that you use the Control-M module for AFT (*Advanced File Transfer*).

Once this module (AFT) has been installed in a Control-M agent suitable for carrying out file transfers, you will be able to use an AFT JobType where you can specify the details of the file transfer.

> You must consider that first you have to create an AFT **connection
>   profile** from the **CCM** (*Control-M Configuration Manager*) where you
>   establish all the necessary information to access the SFTP services
>   (servers, ports, user accounts and passwords, encryption, etc.)